# When to use MKMapView's MKUserTrackingMode vs Location Manager's start updating location?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I'm making an app that tracks a user's location and currently I'm doing this (once user has authorized tracking of their location) with the following code:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    // set map View delegate
    mapView.delegate = self

    // turn on user tracking mode to follow user

    if tracking == true {
    mapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingMode.follow

    } else {
         mapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingMode.none
    }


}
```

This seems to work fine for tracking the user's location and I was wondering when I would use this and when I would use `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` or `stopUpdatingLocation()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use `userTrackingMode` when your sole purpose is to update a map. But sometimes we want the user location for other purposes (e.g. to log it in some database, to use it to see what stores and or location-based special deals we might offer, etc.). In fact, we might use `CLLocationManager` when a map might not be shown at all, or not yet, at least.

So, if you only care about updating a map, then you can use `userTrackingMode`. But if you care about location independent of any visual map, use `CLLocationManager`.